# Problem using RTC using ds3231

Tags: pi-3, i2c, rtc

Trying to get an RTC to load at boot.  I've enabled i2c, that works fine for other components.

/etc/modules contains:

```
snd-bcm2835
i2c-bcm2835
i2c-dev 
rtc-ds3231
```

/etc/rc.local contains:

```
echo ds3231 0x68 > /sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-1/new_device
hwclock -s
```

i2cdetect -y 1 shows UU in the 68 slot

I can set the date using `hwclock` with `-r`, '-w', and `-s` successfully

if I reboot, I get from `hwclock -r`

```
hwclock: The Hardware Clock registers contain values that are either invalid (e.g. 50th day of month) or beyond the range we can handle (e.g. Year 2095).
```

I can then write, read and sync with it again fine.

Any suggestions?!  I've tried replacing the RTC module, but the same thing happens.  Same if I remove the battery from the RTC.

If I remove the battery, the first time I boot it will show the date in the year 2000, but after that it'll go back to the error.

Comment: Solved by following the instruction here:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=161133

Comment: You know self answering is allowed? So if you can expand what is in that link with your own experience that worked for the context you describe, it would be a reasonable answer, no?

Answer (score 1):

The answers involving modprobe and removing fake hwclock are not needed for Stretch era Rasbian and beyond.  Here's the steps that work for me as a reference:

1. Install tools:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install -y i2c-tools   
   sudo apt-get install -y python-smbus
   ```
2. Update `/boot/config.txt` (Note: you can turn I2C 'on' via `sudo raspi-config`, but you need the overlay too to properly load the driver).

   ```
   sudo sh -c "echo dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,ds3231 >> /boot/config.txt"
   sudo sh -c "echo dtparam=i2c_arm=on >> /boot/config.txt"
   ```
3. Update `/lib/udev/hwclock-set` file (`sudo nano /lib/udev/hwclock-set`) and "comment out" the following lines ("comment out" means put a # at the beginning of each of the lines, so they become comments and are ignored by the system).  They should like like:

   ```
   # if [ -e /run/systemd/system ] ; then
   # exit 0
   # fi
   ```
4. Reboot system

   ```
   sudo reboot
   ```
5. Review I2C is working, and get current timestamp from RTC:

   ```
   sudo i2cdetect -y 1 # will show 68 if I2C is on, but UU if overlay is actually active.
   sudo hwclock -r
   ```
6. Review and update reading from hw clock.

   ```
   sudo hwclock -D -r
   date # Get latest date from internet 
   sudo hwclock -w # write that date to HW clock
   sudo hwclock -r # read the value of hw clock again
   ```

References: 
https://learn.adafruit.com/adding-a-real-time-clock-to-raspberry-pi/set-rtc-time
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=161133